# Cache no me permite ingresar a la página

Tags: windows, google-chrome, cache

Recientemente realice un cambio de hospedaje a otro servidor.

Cambié los datos del **DN** del nuevo servidor de hospedaje.

Para mi sorpresa, al ingresar al dominio **www.example.com** me muestra el siguiente mensaje.

**Index of /**

*Apache Server at inidesing.com Port 80*

Pero desde el teléfono móvil, al ingresar al mismo dominio, se aprecia mi página correctamente sin ningún error, es más al realizar cualquier cambio desde el nuevo servidor se muestran desde el móvil los cambios realizados pero en cambio desde el ordenador / laptop no se muestran los cambios realizados muestra el mismo mensaje ya especificado.

**Index of /**

*Apache Server at inidesing.com Port 80*

**Entonces procedí a eliminar el historial.**

En el historial del navegador marqué todas las casillas con la opción de eliminar los elementos almacenados, **El origen de los tiempos**, y borré todos los datos de navegación.

Al visitar nuevamente el dominio desde el ordenador el mismo mensaje sin ninguna solución.

Probé **CCleaner**, pero sigo con el mismo problema.

> Accedí en la dirección **chrome://cache/**, y mostró un millar de páginas, a pesar de haber borrado el historial de navegación.

Entonces no sé, si se están almacenando los datos localmente.

¿Cómo soluciono este problema?

Mi sistema operativo es **Windows 10**

Answer (score 2):

Prueba a acceder a tu "Centro de redes y recursos compartidos" -> "Configuración del adaptador" -> Y ahí haz doble click en el adaptador que utilices para conectarte a internet.

Dentro de ahí, clicka en Propiedades y en Protocolo de Internet v4. y en "Usar las siguientes DNS" pon 8.8.8.8 y 8.8.4.4 (Las DNS de Google).

Cierras la ventana y el navegador, lo abres de nuevo y accedes a la siguiente página: https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/cache

Eliges RR Type NS, escribes la página en cuestión y le das a Flush Cache.

Y con esto deberías poder solucionarlo.

Comment: +1 No sabía que Google permitía hacer flush en sus servidores DNS :P

Answer (score 1):

Más que cache, puede ser un tema de resolución de *DNS* (Domain name server).

Probá sobre la consola de windows (*CMD*):

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Adicionalmente, comprobá en el *host* de windows, no tener ninguna entrada que evite la resolución del servidor de nombres (*DNS*).

Comment: Es un comando nuevo muy útil pero sigue sin funcionar existen algunas otras alternativas porque sigue sin funcionar amigo.

Answer (score 1):

Hola para saber si tu cambio de dominio fue exitoso y se esta resolviendo el ***DNS*** ejecutas en un ***cmd*** de windows después el comando de   ***nslookup*** el cual te devuelve la dirección ***IP*** donde esta alojado el dominio Ej:.

```
C:\Users\Usuario>nslookup
Servidor predeterminado: Nombre del servidor DNS interno
Address:  XXXXXXXXXXX

> www.example.com
Servidor:  Nombre del servidor DNS interno
Address:  IP del DNS interno

Respuesta no autoritativa:
Nombre:  www.example.com
Addresses:  IP del servidor donde esta alojado 

>
```

Si te esta devolviendo bien la IP, donde esta alojado el servidor el problema no esta en el ***DNS*** sino en la forma que colocaste tus directorio, en la carpeta publica del nuevo servidor. Para salir de duda en ese, caso solo tienes que colocar un fichero ***index.php*** dentro de la carpeta de publicación del ***apache***  con el contenido que desees y así compruebas que el servidor esta funcionado bien.

> Estas pruebas del dns has la desde la laptop o pc para que compruebes que te esta accediendo bien al dominio.

Answer (score 0):

En google chrome, dale al F12, esto te abrira la consola de desarrollador.

Con la consola abierta haz click derecho en el boton de actualizar la página(arriba a la izquierda en la barra del buscador) veras que te muestra varias opciones. Dale a la ultima, "Vaciar la cache y cargar de manera forzada"

Ya me diras a ver si hay suerte.

Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

1) Prueba: Pulsando **control + shift + r**

2) Puede que los DNS que cambiaste no esten conectados correctamente al servidor podrias llamar (si es comprado) a la empresa o si es propio revisarlo. Segun lei los cambios pueden tardar hasta 3 dias en ocurrir (otros servidores)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>, de esta forma toda la información de la página, reemplazando y actualizando la del caché

Answer (score 0):

Creo que más que un problema de caché, lo que ocurre es un problema de propagación de DNS.

El tiempo que tarda la propagación de DNS es de unas 72 horas y va ocurriendo por zonas. Por tanto es posible que durante ese período tu sitio web actual se vea correctamente en algunas zonas del planeta y en otras no. O incluso en el mismo país, dependiendo del proveedor de internet. Aunque es extraño que en el móvil funciona y no en el ordenador. Sería interesante saber si estás conectado a la misma red en ambos...

Con respecto al cambio de DNS, pueden ocurrir escenarios como este:

- Mismo dominio: example.com
- Dos cuentas de hosting y dos DNS distintos: h1 (antiguo) y h2 (nuevo)

Supongamos que tienes tu sitio corriendo en Wordpress. En una zona donde el DNS nuevo (h2) no se haya propagado, un usuario entra a tu sitio y escribe un comentario, dicho comentario se almacenará en la base de datos de tu instalación antigua de WP (h1) y se mostrará sólo en aquellos lugares donde h1 esté activo. Pero cuando el cambio se haga, dicho comentario se perderá, no lo verás nunca en h2. No obstante, si entras a la base de datos de h1 mediante cPanel o usando tus credenciales de MySQL, encontrarás dicho comentario.

Existen varias herramientas para comprobar el estado de propagación DNS de tu dominio, entre ellas:

- https://dnschecker.org
- https://www.nslookuptool.com/es/

Por eso se recomienda **no hacer cambios en el contenido hasta no estar seguro de que la propagación ha tenido efecto 100%**.

Si de todos modos piensas que es un problema de caché, puedes revisar el estado de la caché de tu sitio web en Google de dos maneras:

- Haciendo una búsqueda en Google con: `site:example.com` poniendo tu web, sin http://, sin www y sin espacios después de los `:` , y luego dando clic en la flecha verde que verás a la derecha y luego a `En caché`
- También puedes acceder directamente usando esta url: `http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:example.com`

Para despejar dudas sobre si se trata de un problema de caché, puedes probar con otro navegador diferente de Chrome, en el mismo equipo.

Comment: Hola a mi me pasa igual :( amigo conectado en la misma red en el ordenador no se visualiza pero en el móvil si, ahora probando otro navegador pasa el mismo error no muestra la página si no aquel mensaje **index of /**

Comment: @Cedano realmente no creo que sea problemas de DNS por los cambios realizados en el servidor porque si fuese así no se visualizara en el dispositivo móvil o desde otro ordenador conectado en la misma red.

Comment: @May Es extraño. ¿No habrá alguna regla del firewall que bloquée los accesos de tu equipo a esa página? ¿Se conecta bien a otras páginas de otros dominios? ¿Algún bloqueo en el servidor para que tu máquina no pueda ingresar a esa url? Si puede usa alguna herramienta como firebug para ver si te da algún dato relevante al intentar conectar.